# Excel Formula: Outputting multiple column headers based on row data?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table in a monthly calendar format (Dates as column headers) and the data in the rows are marked with the cost for that day for that room eg:

```
        1      2      3    4      5 ....
Room 1 100           100     
Room 2 100         
Room 3        100         100    100
```

What I want to do is for each room, to know the days that the expense of 100 occurs, eg for Room 1, the expense occurs on day and day 3.

I have tried a formula `INDEX($G$3:$AK$3,1, MATCH(100,$G4:$AK4,0))` but it will only show the first column that it appears.

How can I do it so it shows multiple columns?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your worksheet setup as below:

[image]

Add this formula in cell `AI3` and confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and drag down.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$AF$1,1,SMALL(IF(($A$2:$A$100=$AI$1)*($B$2:$AF$100=$AI$2),COLUMN($B$1:$AF$1)),ROW()-ROW($AI$2))),"")`